# $T$-dependence of magnetic susceptibility for the 2D Heisenberg model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, simulations, spin-models, ferromagnetism

As part of a numerical study of the 2D classical ferromagnetic Heisenberg model, I was asked to plot $\ln(\chi)$ vs $T^{-1}$ and determine the $T$-dependence of the magnetic susceptibility in the low-temperature regime. Below is the plot I produced with a Monte Carlo simulation. I could try and fit the tail of the plots with a polynomial or exponential fit function, but the point is that I don't know what to expect and it seems it would be in any case a non-trivial dependence.

I have searched the literature for results but got no luck, so do you have any hints or references that could help me?

EDIT: I've added the linear-linear and log-log plots. The log-log seems to show a linear behaviour but again, I don't know what to expect and I don't see why the book would say to plot $\ln(\chi)$ vs $T^{-1}$. (The book is "*An Introduction to Computer Simulation Methods*" by Harvey Gould, Jan Tobochnik, and Wolfgang Christian)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check how the curve looks like in a linear-linear plot and in a log-log plot? These are the usual first steps to get an intuition about the fit. Just with this log-linear plot, you don't have much information apart from the fact that is not an exponential function. It could be a power law.

Comment: I've added the plots in linear-linear and log-log scales.

Comment: So definitely, the tails are well-fitted by power laws.

Comment: I have to agree on that. Do you have any idea on why this would be the case or why the authors of the books suggest studying the depende of $\chi$ on $T$ at low $T$? Any hint or reference would help.

Comment: It is indeed suspicious that the authors sugested the log-linear plot. From a physical perspective I would also expect an exponential decay, the power law decay is usually linked with the critical slowing down. This is, usually all the quantities have a characteristic scale -exponential laws- and close to the critical point this characteristic scales vanish. However, I've never studied the Heisenberg model. Does it have a critical point as the Ising model? The susceptibility should diverge close to the critical point...Anyway, is never to late for a code revision ;)

Comment: The 2D Heisenberg model does not have a phase transition like the Ising model. This is a result of the Mermin-Wagner theorem. I've found in the literature that it's quite hard to get rid of the finite magnetization even for very big system sizes. Some authors talk of pseudocritical behaviour. In any case, I'll try to check the code again and compare my results with what I've found online.